# Node-Webkit mysql data to news feed

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, json, node-webkit

I working on a news feed tool that we can send remote news messages to a screen. Now i have done the back end of the system and working now on the frontend/client.

I will use node-web kit to show the news on the screen. I have already a connection with the database and it show the messages also in the console log. But i don't get it right to show it on the news feed page.

I try to make it looks like a CNN news feed banner:
[CNN feed banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkLEb.jpg)

Styling is not the problem but i don't get the date from the json (mysql output) to the screen.

The output i get from mysql in the console looks like:

```
[{"id":1,"message":"Test message #1"},{"id":2,"message":"Test message #2"},{"id":3,"message":"Test message #3"}]
```

And the code from the client looks like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NewsFeed</title>

  <script>

  var mysql      = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'XXXXX',
    user     : 'XXXXX',
    password : '',
    database : 'XXXXX'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM message', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      json = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log(json);
    });
  });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do someone know how to read the Json information from the console to the HTML view?

And also is there a way the let the news feed automatic update when there is add a new message to the database?

UPDATE: I think auto refresh is not the best way. So i was thinking about remote refresh. The idea is;

User login on a backend system add a message and then press on a button to reload the page.

Like this image: [Idea reload remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G16B3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

First of all, add a node element in you DOM which will contail all the messages.

```
<body>
    <h1>Messages</h1>
    <div id="message-container"></div>
</body>
```

Then make you function write in the DOM:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM message', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      json = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log(json);

      var container = document.getElementById("message-container")

      // Use this in case you can't perform a more precise query
      container.innerHTML = "";

      results.forEach(function(item){
          var node = document.createElement("p");
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(item.message); 

          node.appendChild(textnode);
          container.appendChild(node); 
      })
    });
});
```

To keep you data up to date, you can do some good ol' polling:

```
function startTimer() {
    setTimeout(query, 10000)
}

function query() {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM message', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      json = JSON.stringify(results);
      console.log(json);

      var container = document.getElementById("message-container")

      // Use this in case you can't perform a more precise query
      container.innerHTML = "";

      results.forEach(function(item){
          var node = document.createElement("p");
          var textnode = document.createTextNode(item.message); 

          node.appendChild(textnode);
          container.appendChild(node); 
          startTimer()
      })
    });
}

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
    query()
})
```

This way you have a first request. Once that is done, the app waits 10 seconds and prompt a second request. After that one is done, it waits for 10 seconds and so on...

Comment: Thank this have help (: Now i only need to make the auto update function when there is a new message.

Did you maybe know how i can make that ?

Comment: Actually I do not know how this mysql module works, but I don't think there is other way to update data different from polling, see Edit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have try that but after a reload all the message are double in the feed. 

So is the away to reload the page/script with a button on the backend and with nodejs ?

First time i use nodejs for real projects. Try already to remotly to push: <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1"> but don't get it working

Comment: See the further edit. I added a line to clean the container on every request. Actually this is not the best way to achieve the result, but this should do the trick. I think you should perform a more precise query (maybe getting only feeds in the last 10 seconds) 

P.S.: do not forget to upvote useful comments :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have try it and it works i don't have any dubble messages in the feeder. But now it resets ever 10 second and the feed will start agian with scroll effect. 

Sorry for asking so much, but its not posibale to reset the feed with a button on the backend with nodejs or something ?.. And i will give a upvote but dont have any reputation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what do you mean by "reset the feed with a button on the backend". Give me an example